# Separate console application project outputs in TFS drop folder, similar to _PublishedWebSites

Tags: tfs

I have a large solution with 10+ web applications and 10+ console and windows service applications.

When building All.sln, in the drop location, i've got single folder with all console application dlls, and web application dlls mixed.

Also, i've got _PublishedWebsites folder, which contains nicely separated web applications in their own folders, ready to deploy.

How to get console applicaitons in their own folders, each with only necessary referenced dlls, just the way web applications are separated in _PublishedWebsites?

Looks like it's possible with custom 'master' msbuild file:
[msbuild SLN and still get separate project outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628739/msbuild-sln-and-still-get-separate-project-outputs), but how to achive the same with regular TFS 2010 build?

Comment: This looks similar to a problem I had : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504202/problems-with-msbuild-outputpath-and-outdir-in-tfs2010

Comment: If you have a problem where all `Content` marked as `Copy Always` is copied to the root folder and not hierarchically see my answer to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732824/customise-build-build-output-for-specific-projects).

Answer (score 2):

there's a NuGet package you can install that will do this.

see http://www.nuget.org/packages/publishedapplications

Comment: Yes I think I was using it last year with 2012

Comment: If you have a problem where all `Content` marked as `Copy Always` is copied to the root folder and not hierarchically see my answer to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732824/customise-build-build-output-for-specific-projects).